# How programmatically save a website as if it has been rendered in a browser (the javascript executed)

Tags: html, web-scraping

In browsers you can 'save as' a page, and get the current html after the javascript has executed. Is there a way to do this programmatically? Call some other tool perhaps? Maybe remotely make the browser do something? It can be hacky - I just need it for home usage.

Comment: did you check out tools like PhantomJS ?

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: What language do you want to do this with ? For Java (and some other languages), you can try Selenium.

Comment: I don't really care which language I use, but I already have some code (nim), and phantomjs seems interesting, so I'll see if I can utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you want to 'save as' page or if you want to take scereenshot after javascript is executed. Its two different things.

In first case you can use simple `wget -r <web address>` [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)

In second case you will need to use some more sophisticated scraper lets say phantom js should be able to execute js and after take a screenshot:
http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Hope it helps!
Have a nice day